# noremap <C-j> to {

Tags: key-bindings

Because I'm on a german keyboard layout `{` and `}` are relatively hard to type.

As a workaround especially for latex I used `inoremap <C-j> {` and `inoremap <C-l> }` which works great. After internalizing these I also tried to use them in all other modes via `noremap <C-j> {` e.g. such that `/<C-j>` would search for `{` and `ci<C-j>` change in curly braces, but this doesn't work.

I also tried `onoremap` and `lnoremap` which both failed. But it does work in normal mode i.e. `<C-j>` moves a paragraph backward.

As far as I understand `/` and `c` should both go into "operator-pending" mode, so that `map` and `omap` should both work. I also couldn't find information that `<C-j>` is "special" like `<C-h>`, and I guess in that case `imap` shouldn't work either. Am I overlooking something?

I tested this on vim 7.4 with an empty config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### /<C-j>

`/` doesn't enter operator-pending mode, it enters command-line mode.

For this, you want `noremap!` which applies to insert mode and command-line mode.

`:help map-modes` does imply that your attempt of `lnoremap` should have worked, but `:help language-mapping`, a bit further down in the file, explains why this is not the case:

> Generally: Whenever a character is to be typed that is part of the text in the buffer, not a Vim command character.
>
> [...]
>
> [Language mappings] are only used for typed characters.

`:help i_CTRL-j` links to the insert-mode documentation's "Special keys" section: `Ctrl-J` is not a character which gets inserted into the buffer, but instead is a control character that tells Vim to begin a new line<sup>*</sup>.

### ci<C-j>

`c` *does* enter operator pending mode, and you will find after having run `onoremap <C-j> {` as you describe, that `c<c-j>` works as expected.

The problem is `ci{` works differently to how you are imagining. In this command the *two* keystrokes `i{` are a text object (`:help text-objects`), and operator-pending mode maps don't apply in the middle of text objects. I think the fix for these will require a bit more verbosity:

```
onoremap i<c-j> i{
onoremap a<c-j> a{
" etc.
```

<sub>* If you're thinking that this is just a roundabout way of saying that a `LF` character is inserted when you type one, consider how Vim will save different bytes into the file depending on the current value of `'fileformat'` — it's a subtle distinction, I agree.</sub>

Comment: Huh, I really never got that there is a difference between command characters and "typed characters".  But of course otherwise stuff like `<C-o>` wouldn't work in insert mode. I thought `c-j` was simply mapped to `enter` in insert mode. And that mappings work on "syntactical units" instead simply on the character stream also never occured to me. Very informative, thanks!